# Wrap capture group in quotes if it contains non-digit characters?

Tags: regex

I can't seem to find any answers on how to wrap the resulting capture group in quotes when using regex.

If I got this:

`Abcd   abcd    12345`

`Abcd   1234    12345`

I want this:

`"Abcd" "abcd"  12345`

or this:

`"Abcd" 1234    12345`

How can I do something like this:

`"$1"   (?$2=[^0-9] \"$2\" | $2)` in the replace input?

Or in other words:
I need to check if the result of the capture group (the result of the match) is of one or the other type and then wrap in quotation marks or not.

Read as: "if capture group contains non digit characters replace it with the value wrapped in quotation marks, otherwise replace with the number".

I can't seem to figure out how to do the actual IF / THEN in the result input – or understand how it would work in the reg itself (lacking a mind map here).

---

Additional info:

I've got these two variations (notice the different second group):

`string-digits  digits  digits  datetime    datetime    string  string  digits-digits   string`

`string-digits  string-digits-whitespace    digits  datetime    datetime    string  string  string-digits   string`

So far I'm trying to use this regex:

`(.+)   (THIS IS THE TRICKY PART)   ([0-9]+)    ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+)    [0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+  (.+)    (.+)    (.+-[0-9]+) (.+)`

I need to create this:

```
{
    "unique-key" : "$1",
    "unique-key" : $2,      <-- this second capture group should be wrapped in quotes if the value is not an integer.
    "unique-key" : $3,
    "unique-key" : "$4",
    "unique-key" : "$5",
    "unique-key" : "$6",
    "unique-key" : "$6",
    "unique-key" : "$7",
    "unique-key" : "$8"
}
```

Comment: Does `(?<!\S)(?!\d+(?!\S))(\S+)` => `"$1"` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJj5D2/1)) work as expected?

Comment: I think like this `(?<!\S)[^\s\d]+(?!\S)` and replace using the whole match https://regex101.com/r/2QGOcB/1

Comment: It seems to ignore the number version ... only capturing the string version as far as I can make it work. And I'm not sure where the actual quotations marks gets generated.

Comment: Where are you using the regex? How?

Comment: Why do you want to replace the number version with itself? You only want the match for the non numberversions to replace with the quotes right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly - numbers should be left without changes. So, only words containing non-digit characters should be surrounded with quotes.

Then, the pattern may look like:

```
([^\s]*[^\d\s]+[^\s]*)
```

What is matched by this pattern should be replaced with "$1"

Comment: This also ignores the digit only versions.

Comment: Well, then the problem is not with regex but with substitution. The pattern could look like this: `(([^\s]*[^\d\s]+[^\s]*)|(\d+))` and then the matched string would be either in the 2nd or 3rd group. But still it would need some logic to check which group is not empty and use it with or without quotes.